# How can I uncheck a checked checkbox programmatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have the following sample:

```
<input name="Opt1" id="Opt1" type="checkbox" value="1" alt="1948" title="RQlevel1" src="2" checked="checked" onclick="levels();"/>  <label style="cursor:pointer" for="OptID12851948">PADI Advanced Open Water</label>

<input name="Opt2" id="Opt2" type="checkbox" value="2" alt="1953" title="RQlevel2" src=""  onclick="levels();"/>  <label style="cursor:pointer" for="OptID19521953">PADI Rescue</label>

<input name="Opt3" id="Opt3" type="checkbox" value="3" alt="1957" title="RQlevel2" src=""  onclick="levels();"/>  <label style="cursor:pointer" for="OptID19521953">PADI Rescue2</label>
```

If I click PADI Advanced Open Water checkbox, which will then call the levels() JavaScript function, how can I programmatically uncheck this checked checkbox using jQuery?

I have tried the following but doesn't work:

```
if ($("input[value='1']:checked").attr("checked")){
    $("input[value='1']:checked").attr(“checked”, false);
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`removeAttr`](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/):

```
$("input[value='1']:checked").removeAttr('checked');
```

Or with recent versions of jQuery, you can use [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop2):

```
$("input[value='1']:checked").prop('checked', false);
```

Answer (score 2):

If your using jQuery 1.6 and up you should really use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) for this

In addition your selector already determines that the input is checked.  There is no need to duplicate that by checking the attribute or propery.

```
if ($("input[value='1']:checked").length) { 
    $("input[value='1']:checked").prop("checked", false); 
}
```

However if you are using a version of jQuery lower than 1.6 this will work by using removeAttr().

```
if ($("input[value='1']:checked").length) { 
    $("input[value='1']:checked").removeAttr("checked"); 
}
```